# i update djang1.3.1 to djang1.4 , error: MOD_PYTHON ERROR

Tags: python, django, mod-python

I updated djang1.3.1 to djang1.4. 
In my local env ,that's fine.
but when i ci my code to server ,error happened!
in my server , i can use 'python manage.py shell'
and can 'import settings', that's all right,
but still have this error, who can help me!

> finally, i uninstalled apache , and installed nginx + uwsgi ,fixed
>   this problem.......

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1537, in HandlerDispatch
default=default_handler, arg=req, silent=hlist.silent)

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1229, in _process_target
result = _execute_target(config, req, object, arg)

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1128, in _execute_target
result = object(arg)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/modpython.py", line 180, in handler
return ModPythonHandler()(req)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/modpython.py", line 142, in __call__
self.load_middleware()

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 39, in load_middleware
for middleware_path in settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 184, in inner
self._setup()

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 95, in __init__
raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))

ImportError: Could not import settings 'guihuame.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named guihuame.settings
```

my python version

```
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:57:41) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
>>> django.VERSION
(1, 4, 0, 'final', 0)
```

use manage.py

```
python manage.py shell
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:57:41) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> import settings
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named settings
>>> import guihuame.settings
>>>
```

thx!

my document tree is 
guihuame 
-- manage.py
-- guihuame (contains **init**.py wsgi.py settings.py urls.py)
-- other apps

my wsgi.py , wsgi.py and settings.py are in the same folder

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/web/trunk/guihuame/')
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "guihuame.settings")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: You need to set your PYTHONPATH correctly. Show your WSGI file.

Comment: this is my wsgi.py , see the bottom of the question

Comment: Unless you have a further guihuame directory under `'/var/web/trunk/guihuame/'` you probably want to change that to `'/var/web/trunk/'`

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a line to `wsgi.py` to add the location of your `guihuame` module to the PYTHONPATH:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'Wherever guihuame is')
```

Update:
It's up to you to actually provide the location of `guihame`. However, don't do string manipulations on your paths. Python will choose the correct separator. If there is an issue with that, use `normpath`.

Note also that `os.path.split(os.path.dirname(__file__))[0]` is selecting either your filesystem root, or more likely, just one level below it. This is probably not what you want.

Comment: import sys
root_path = os.path.split(os.path.dirname(__file__))[0]
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(root_path, 'guihuame').replace('\\','/'))    it doesn't work~

Comment: @yzliu What you have pasted is not valid python, and it is not the code I have suggested. Update your answer with the current state of your wsgi.py and I *may* be able to help you, if you also describe the nature of the error you are experiencing.